# Use Mavan-Pulish upload artifact to Nexus in env Gradle7+ failed

Tags: upload, android-gradle-plugin, http-headers, nexus, maven-publish

Use Mavan-Pulish upload artifact to Nexus3 in env Gradle7+ failed.

- the env:

> - id : 'maven-publish'
> - gradle-7.3-rc-3-bin
> - com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3
> - Nexus:nexus-3.35.0-02

- part gradle code:

```
publishing{
    publications{
        release(MavenPublication){
            groupId = 'xxx.xx.xx'
            artifactId = 'xxx'
            version = 'vesionnbr'
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/xxx.aar")

            pom{
                url = 'http://ip:port/repository/libs'
            }
        }
    }
    repositories{
        maven{
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
            url 'http://ip:port/repository/libs'
            credentials{
                username 'xxx'
                password 'xxx....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- the error log :

> Execution failed for task ':project:publishReleasePublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'release' to repository 'maven'
> **Could not write to resource 'http://........../maven-metadata.xml'.**
> > **ip:port failed to respond **
>
> - Exception is:
>   **org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':xxxx:publishReleasePublicationToMavenRepository'.
>   Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not write to resource 'http://ip:port/repository/ipu_libs_snapshot/com/ai/ipu/ipu-mobile-framework/maven-metadata.xml'.**
>   at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
>   at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.putFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:61)
>   at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.put(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:136)
>   at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher$ModuleArtifactPublisher$1.run(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:279)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.NetworkOperationBackOffAndRetry.withBackoffAndRetry(NetworkOperationBackOffAndRetry.java:50)
>   at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher$ModuleArtifactPublisher.putResource(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:276)
>   at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher$ModuleArtifactPublisher.publish(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:232)
>   at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher.publish(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:92)
>   at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.MavenRemotePublisher.publish(MavenRemotePublisher.java:61)
>   at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.ValidatingMavenPublisher.publish(ValidatingMavenPublisher.java:50)
>   at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository$1.publish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:111)
>   at org.gradle.api.publish.internal.PublishOperation.run(PublishOperation.java:43)
>   ... 120 more
>   **Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: ip:port failed to respond
>   at** org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
>   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
>   at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>   at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:170)
>   at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:150)
>   at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceUploader.upload(HttpResourceUploader.java:41)
>   at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.upload(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:79)
>   at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceUploader$UploadOperation.run(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceUploader.java:98)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
>   at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceUploader.upload(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceUploader.java:44)
>   at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.put(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:133)

Once i thought maybe it is the net question ,not the gradle code
But when i use plugin maven and downgrade gradle and androidtool plugin version,it success!The nexus should be normal；And I can upload success everytime;

- the success env：

> id : maven
> gradle-6.5-all
> com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2

- gradle code:

```
uploadArchives{
    ......
}
```

And the same question i found is [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13537),But no useful solution provided;
Anyone ever found this question or can give some useful suggetion for me ,thinks!

Comment: I just use command to upload file in Android Stuido ,it work success!But i used to use the gradle window on the right，it failed,and AS has no proxy setting; so strange!

Comment: the issue had been solved;maybe i often open vpn or charles，the ide‘s proxy show warning 'you have JVM property “https.proxyHost“ set to “127.0.0.1“';so i set vm options '-DsocksProxyPort';then the solve the  issue;later i may find why the queston happen;